# How do I combine multiple form inputs into a single object with SimpleFormController in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have an object called Person that has the following properties:

```
int id;
Name name;
String address;
Date birthday;
String email;
String note;
```

The Name class has these properties:

```
String firstName;
String middleName;
String lastName;
```

In my form, I have these input fields:

```
<tr>
    <td>First Name:</td>
    <td><form:input path="firstName" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Middle Name:</td>
    <td><form:input path="middleName" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Last Name:</td>
    <td><form:input path="lastName" /></td>
</tr>
```

How will I be able to retrieve the value of the name input fields and turn it into a Name object before passing it to the Person object that will be created by the SimpleFormController? I'm pretty sure I need to use the initBinder() method, but I don't know how to start.

I'm using Spring 3.0, and yes, I know that SimpleFormController is deprecated already, but I still intend to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write:

```
<form:input path="name.firstName" />
...
```

in you jsp. And need to override the [formBackingObject](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/AbstractFormController.html#formBackingObject(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)) Method, so that it retuns an empty Person object with an reference to an emtpy name object

```
protected Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request) {
   Person person = new Person();
   person.Name = new Name();
   return person;
}
```

Thats all, you do not need to write your own binding.

Comment: That solved my first error regarding the formBackingObject() method. It produces a Data Binding error when submitting. I can't figure out the root of the cause though. You think it has something to do with the Name field?

Comment: @Terence Ponce: you mean 'name'? -- I dont thinks so.

Comment: Oh, nevermind. The cause is unrelated to this. Your solution regarding my problem worked. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently, the error is caused by the birthday field not being bound to the object. It's a whole new problem though.

Comment: This method is now deprecated. One suggestion is to write a class object that temporary stores multiple types of data, and you use this class object for the form model attribute, so you can update/fetch the data you need for multiple form inputs from this class object.